# up arrow image in xml drawable: Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a listactivity it should look like the following (ie listview with border and an arrow pointing upwards at right side of the listview),

[image]

So far i have the listview with border and rounded corners. But i have no idea how to add upward arrow at top right side.

My code:

list_border.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
     <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid android:color="#CCCCCC" />

                <padding
                    android:bottom="3dp"
                    android:left="3dp"
                    android:right="3dp"
                    android:top="3dp" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

listborder.axml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/notification_list_border"
        android:layout_height="300dp">
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I tried to add arrow image in xml. But it isnt working

```
    <item android:right="10dp">
            <bitmap
                android:src="@drawable/up_icon"
                android:gravity="top|right" />
        </item>
```

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: I think you a nine patch image might help you achieving this

Comment: @playmaker420 I think 9 patch image is to stretch according to the content. But my listview remains same size always. I just need an arrow on top. Does that make sense?

Comment: Set the 9patch background with the arrow to listview's parent . And set appropriate margin to listview.Would that help?